# Eigen - diagonal update of sparse matrix

Tags: sparse-matrix, eigen

What's the fastest way to edit the diagonal of a sparse matrix in Eigen? I've already filled it using triplets but I occasionally need to change all the diagonal values (they were already set to nonzero).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If acceptable, you could simply use their indices like

```
sp_mat(i, i)
```

As each access involves a binary search, the performance may not be satisfied. In this case, you could still achieve better performance with some restrictions.

1. You  don't change the underlying layout of the matrix, e.g. adding/deleting nnzs, compressing;
2. You will access the diagonal repeatedly.

With these restrictions, you could store the pointers of the diagonal components so that you can access the data later in O(1) time. You could get the pointer with

```
&sp_mat(i, i)
```

Comment: Right, those are exactly my conditions. Know how to access the pointers to those positions?

Answer (score 3):

To complete kangshiyin answer, you can also edit the diagonal through dense vector expressions, for instance to add 1 to each diagonal element:

```
sp_mat.diagonal().array() += 1;
```

**Warning**: this will work only if the diagonal elements already exist, which is the case in the original question.

Comment: Right, for me the elements will already exist. Would you expect that expression to be faster/slower than storing the pointers and changing directly?

Comment: nope this approach will still involve the binary searches every time, but  it's easier to write in some cases.

Comment: Is .diagonal() available in v3.2.9?